# Graphical-output - trivial solutions

Tags: discussion, rules, graphical-output

I found question where author ask about reproduce logo (reproduction do not need to be identical). In one of answer we see solution with low resolution logo picture made by hand

[image]

This solution indeed is very small 202 bytes - but the question is: does this approach (create low resolution picture of desired output) should be allowed for `graphical-output` questions?

Comment: The problem with that question specifically, is that it doesn't supply its own rigorous definition of what the output is allowed to be: "The logo can be any size BUT has to be recognisable (each hexagon part has to be visible)."

Comment: Please add a link to the challenge! (It is this one here for anyone looking for it: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193093/codegolf-the-hex)

Comment: I don't think we have anything to discuss here, the challenge was closed because the specs were not objective, so what you're asking is not an issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not an issue, as the challenge itself is unclear.

Answer (score 6):

To put the comments into an full answer:

This is an issue with the question not being clear as to what is a valid answer (and the question seems to be closed for this reason).  Graphical output questions should clearly state what they require of the output image to be clear.

Once this is done by the question it should be easy to determine what is a valid answer and no need to discuss it on meta.