# What should I do with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently posted [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193093/codegolf-the-hex) on codegolf. The idea was simple : reproduce an hexagonal logo, graphically or in ASCII art.
At first i thought it would be good enouth to be interessing, but the lack of acceptability criterias kind of engraved the challenge. I tried to add some explanations, but it ended up on hold as too broad.

I am here now, with a challenge I don't find interessing at all now, put on hold, without any clue in what to do with this. Should I try to modify the challenge and mess up with the answers ? Should I let it go ? Should I simply delete the question ?

Comment: You can't exactly delete the question now. There are answers.

Answer (score 11):

Personally I think your challenge's idea is good, it has already caused a creative answer in [Logo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193126/81663) but lacks more specific details.

I think this comment with 7 likes under your post should give a clue:

> `recognisable` is very subjective, I'd suggest giving a reference ASCII version that has to be matched.

I would suggest to clarify details as much as possible, specially about the graphical outputs and what is exactly accepted and what isn't to avoid doubts and more questions.

You can also look at other questions in similar tags (for example [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output)) with high votes to get ideas.

Normally if you edit your original question and address all the concerns and questions posted in the comments, people will start vote to re-open the question.

And of course use [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for future question, so other experienced users can mention any issues and discuss the idea before the question goes live.

This question on meta is also related to your challenge: [Graphical-output - trivial solutions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18101/81663)